# What's the shortest way to say this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, expressions

I would like to offer customers a family size french fries. The total amount or number of fries that a customer buys is divided into two equal groups. The first group has curly fries. The second group contains normal fries.

I would like to shorten this sentence without losing the meaning. Here's what I can think of:

> You can get a family size french fries that half of it is curly and the other half is regular fries.

I know that there might be grammar/structure mistakes. Is this sentence short and correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the preposition *with* in place of your first *that*; this lets you remove the two instances of *is*:

> You can get a family-size french fries **with** half curly fries and half regular fries

Comment: Or, _We offer a family-size french fries, with half curly and half regular fries._

Answer (score 0):

*You can get . . .* is a statement, not an offer.

Also, there shouldn't be an article in its construction unless you preface it with a countable noun.

> Can I offer you **an order of** family-size french fries that equally contains curly and regular?